# Regex for persian with numbers

Tags: c#, regex

I want to write a regex for these input samples:

```
اشک12345
اشکـ12345
```

My idea:

```
"^[آ-ی][آ-ی][آ-ی][\ـ]?\d{5}"
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: What do you want to do with that regex?

Comment: Regex for :اشک12345
اشکـ12345

Comment: Do You need for Matching characters or for parse some groups ?

Comment: I want to Matching characters.Tnx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to use another regex expression:

```
[0-9]*[\u0600-\u06FF]*
```

Or

```
[\u0600-\u06FF]*[ـ]?[\d{5}]+
```

Or even

```
[\w{Arabic}]*[ـ]?[\d{5}]+
```

For matching 2 groups You could use

```
(?'head'[\w{Arabic}]{3})[ـ]?(?'index'[\d{5}]+)
```

As result will be 2 groups:

```
head: اشک
index: 12345
```